# ExtJS disable tab panel lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, extjs, extjs4

I have some content inside of an ExtJS tab panel that I'm doing DOM manipulation on via a jQuery library.

Currently I'm having to do a manual call to activate the specific tab (so that Ext will actually build the DOM) before I run the jQuery code (I'm using a library to build a barcode image).

Is there a way to setup the tab panel so that anytime an `.update()` is applied to the panel it will immediately manipulate the DOM as opposed to only doing it when the panel becomes active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your panel with the option `deferredRender: false`, so all tabs will be rendered when the panel is created instead of just rendering them once you activate them.

Comment: The barcode library that I'm using is written for jQuery so I don't believe so.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to test it last night, but I plugged that in this morning and it worked great!